# Optimal use of a Synapse Analytics stored procedure

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm working with a Synapse Analytics dedicated SQL pool and I need to create some stored procedures.
In particular, I have to create a procedure to manage some tens of thousands of rows.
A Synapse stored procedure is an interpreted code respect to the pre-compiled code of a SQL Server stored procedure. This is a very important difference between these two data platforms.
So, which are the best or right practices to follow to use a Synapse stored procedure optimally respect to SQL Server, please? Thanks